# Will Err.Number perisist across if statements in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, error-handling

In code below, will err.Number be NON-ZERO in second if, when an error has occurred within the first if at 'conn.Execute sql'

```
if err.number = 0 and error_flag = 0 then
   conn.Execute sql 'AN ERROR OCCURS HERE
end if  

if err.number <> 0 then
   error_flag = 1
   if tranCount = 1 then 
       conn.RollbackTrans
       tranCount = 0
   end if 
end if
```

Comment: Your error_flag variable is redundant.  I believe you may be overthinking the logic you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  You need to use `err.Clear` to clear the last value.

Also, if statements are not different scopes.  You wouldn't expect them to be different anyway.